# How to create duplicate webpack chunk files, one with and one without a hash?

Tags: javascript, webpack, build, output, config

I have a webpack config which outputs a file with a hash:

```
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
```

But I also want a duplicate (could be a symlink) of that file to be created in the same dist folder but *without* the hash in the filename, so that I can reference it for testing purposes from another static html page (actually via a file:// url). How do I do that? It seems like only one filename format can be output. I had a look at symlink-webpack-plugin but I can't see how to refer to the output file with its hash reference (issue at https://github.com/hmsk/symlink-webpack-plugin/issues/7), and I also had a look at copy-webpack-plugin but that isn't intended for copying built files. What options do I have here?

Comment: Addition - I see that I can access the hash value using the `ExtendedAPIPlugin`, and create a symlink that way, but I don't know how to access the created `__webpack_hash__` variable within the symlink-webpack-plugin config string

Comment: You can specify two entry points and include/exclude the folder. There must be a better option than this though..